# How to skip a component whenever required?

Tags: angular

The first time user is logged in and after logging in the user is routed to another component to fill some more details. 
After filling those details user log out and again login then I want that user must not get that component again where he/she added details rather he/she must be redirected to the home page.

Please tell me the way how can I solve this particular problem.

I have no code samples to show. But need to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Which topic..??

Comment: Start reading and think about what sounds closest to what you're trying to do. Then try to adapt that. This is programming.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate). Guard your component with a `CanActivate` and check if the user has filled out their details already. When the details have been filled out return a `UrlTree` object that navigates them to the home page. When the details have **not** been filled out return `true`.